# I want to find least among the two dates of different column in teradata

Tags: teradata

```
LEAST(DATE(CAP_REMEDIATION.DATE_OF_AUDIT),  
      DATE(CAP_REMEDIATION.START_DATE_REQUEST))
```

I am using this to find the minimum date between two dates.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the objective content particular question, but: when do people learn, how to [state a proper](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question? This includes a meaningful topic, proper text in the question itself as well as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Teradata didn't define `LEAST/GREATEST` for the date/time types (stupid, at least fixed in TD16.10).

If it's only two columns the easiest way is good ol' CASE:

```
CASE WHEN CAP_REMEDIATION.DATE_OF_AUDIT < CAP_REMEDIATION.START_DATE_REQUEST
     THEN CAP_REMEDIATION.DATE_OF_AUDIT
     ELSE CAP_REMEDIATION.START_DATE_REQUEST
END
```

If the datatypes are actually timestamps and you want a date:

```
CAST(previous_case_expression AS DATE)
```